ThoughtSpot: connect\link between parameters from different models
I have a few answers created from different models.
Each model has the same parameter named "Time Granularity".
In each model\answer the data shown based on this parameter.
After adding the answers to a liveboard I see the parameters (same) multiple times
on the top of the liveboard.
Is there any way to connect between them and have 1 connected\linked parameter?

I've tried a few solutions suggested by GPT but nothing worked.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
